string response objects are not captured in output but are present in response variable
When testing a similar url, that returns a string object, the response is not being returned in the console or report.  While these can be viewed by adding print statements, can these type of response outputs be configured like others, to return in traffic logs for console and reporting?
Sample scenario:
  Scenario: Get String Response
    Given url 'https://safetechpageencryptionvar.chasepaymentech.com/pie/v1/12300000000456/getkey.js'
    When method GET
    * print 'response:',response
    * print 'response.type:',responseType

Response showing missing payload result


Having a pluggable logger is certainly good to have, but not the case now. Open source code-contributions are the best way to get this into future versions of Karate sooner.
That said, note that there are hooks for http requests that you can explore in the mean time: Karate: Is there a http-request hook in karate, that gets called automatically after every API call, and whose behaviour I can modify?
And combined with ways to do grab the internal Logger you can get very far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78354696/143475

Sounds like a bug as you mentioned, likely due to the absence of a pluggable logger, so possibly a future enhancement and documentation update needed to warn users about comments not showing
